# How can I count the view of a Specific post by a User ? Count every User just Once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

We have user and news model, in the news model we have e `viewsCount` field, I want to increment this view count when a `GET` request is made by a `User`.

When a specific user makes a `GET` request, the view count will increment one, every user just one view.

```
const NEWSModel = new Schema({
    viewesCount: { type: Number },
    Publisher: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    LikesCount: { type: Number },
    DislikeCount: { type: Number },
    Comments: CommenTs
});
```

Every user can view the news as many times as wants, but just can make one view. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you Can change your model like and then whenever you get a news just push the user id to the viewedBy field.

> news.viewedBy.push(user id)

````
  viewedBy: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }]
}); ```
````

Comment: or you can use addtoset operator too if you want

Answer (score 0):

If you have not a lot of users, you can add additional field to news model like `users_viewed` which would be array of unique user ids.

And make additional check before incrementing views count.

If user, who requested news is already in this `users_viewed` array, you skip any additional actions.
If don't, increment views counter.

But if you do have a lot of users, it's better to store views counter in Redis to skip request to database and increment in memory counter.

The logic for storing and showing data would be the same, but you'll reduce load on your database and speed up the whole process.

**[UPDATE]** According to your comment, about number of users.

To make things work you can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).
First of all, after request for a news from a client, you can store all the news data in your cache (to reduce number of requests to your database).
Now you have few possible ways to handle number of views.

I think, the easiest to implement would be to add user unique identifier to [SET](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets). And return number of users in SET using [SCARD](https://redis.io/commands/scard);

In this solution you wouldn't need to check if user already watched the news, because set data structure holds only unique values (the same reason why do we need to use user's unique identifier).

And you just use 2 redis requests, which is pretty good for heavy load services.

Comment: thank you so much <3 the user counts will be more than 10000 so lets check the second one,

Comment: @em.d I've updated the answer with explanation how to make things work with redis.

Comment: @em.d if my answer helps, don't hesitate to upwote it :) Or if it works, I'd be glad if you choose it as correct to help other users with same problem to find best solution

Answer (score 0):

You can have another field called `viewedBy` of type `array` in which you can store users ids. Then it will be easier to check if a user already viewed your post or to count them.

**File:** news.model.js

```
const News = new Schema({
  viewedBy: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }],
  // other properties...
});
```

**File:** news.controller.js

```
const user = User.find({...}); // get current user
const news = News.find({...}); // get a news

/* 
  Update views count by adding the current user id if it's not already added
  Thanks to '$addToSet', the update() function will do nothing if the user id it's already there)
*/
news.update({ $addToSet: { viewedBy: user._id } });

// Getting the views count
console.log('Total views:', news.viewedBy.length);
```

More about `$addToSet`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/